# DirectX 11 Multiple Constant Buffers

Tags: c++, buffer, directx-11

I'm trying to make my bounding boxes render on top of the models however I can't get them both to render at the same time. I've narrowed it down to it being a constant buffer issue, so I've set them into 2 different slots e.g.

***BoundingBox***

```
//Constant Buffer Code!
CONSTANT_BUFFER0 cb0_values;

cb0_values.WorldViewProjection = (*world) * (*view) * (*proj);

//Draw the buffer
m_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(8, 0, 0);

m_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(m_pConstantBuffer1, 0, 0, &cb0_values, 0, 0);
m_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(1, 1, &m_pConstantBuffer1);
```

***Models***

```
m_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(m_pConstantBuffer, 0, 0, &modelValues, 0, 0);
m_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &m_pConstantBuffer);

m_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(m_pVShader, 0, 0);
m_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(m_pPShader, 0, 0);
m_pImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(m_pInputLayout);

m_pImmediateContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_pSampler0);
m_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &m_pTexture0
```

However, this doesn't work and only the models appear correctly and my cube is nowhere to be seen, however if I comment out the model draw and do:

```
m_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(m_pConstantBuffer1, 0, 0, &cb0_values, 0, 0);
m_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &m_pConstantBuffer1);
```

I can see my cube but no models (obviously), there must be some simple concept I'm not grasping but I can't work it out.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

After more wall-headbutting I finally figured it out, it was due to the input layout and shaders getting set in my model but then not changed back when it came to render the box again.

TLDR - ***BoundingBox*** draw needed

```
UINT stride = sizeof(POS_COL_VERTEX);
UINT offset = 0;
m_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

//Constant Buffer Code!
CONSTANT_BUFFER0 cb0_values;

cb0_values.WorldViewProjection = (*world) * (*view) * (*proj);

m_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(m_pVertexShader, 0, 0);
m_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(m_pPixelShader, 0, 0);
m_pImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(m_pInputLayout);
```